# setting multiple sort descriptors

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a array of objects and need to sort it by rating and after by number of votes descendent(so that if two 5 stars rated elements compare, the one with the most votes should be first)

Is it possible to sort a NSArray by two descriptors:first after rating and then after votes count?

I've found on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

something like `sortUsingDescriptors:` but i can't find it anywhere in the docs, think it's deprecated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortRating = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"rating" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortVotes = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"votes" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortedArray = [orignalAray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortRating, sortVotes, nil]];
[sortRating release], sortRating = nil;
[sortVotes release], sortVotes = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically right.  On NSArray there is the

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

method.  This will return a new array, sorted according to various descriptors.

```
- (void)sortUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
```

does exist, but is on *NSMutableArray*, which might explain why you couldn't find it in the documentation for NSArray.  It accomplishes the same goal, but sorts the array you call it on, rather than returning a new array.  Neither is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey@"rating" ascending:NO], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey@"date" ascending:NO], nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors`. Here is the documentation: `NSArray` [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

E.g:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortRating = nil;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDate = nil;

NSSortDescriptor *sortRating = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"rating" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [auxArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortRating,sortDate,nil]];

[sortRating release];
sortRating = nil;

[sortDate release];
sortDate = nil;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your code will not compile and you are leaking sortRating and sortDate

Comment: Still will not compile. The reason it will not compile is because you are redefine in the variables names `sortRating` and `sortDate`. Also you are releasing an object called `sortDescriptor` which isn't defined and you do not release `sortRating` and `sortDate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one NSArray use this one:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"x_date" ascending:TRUE];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"x_time" ascending:TRUE];
[tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1, nil]];
```